# The travis' matrix.include not working on multiple os

Tags: travis-ci

I use matrix.include to trigger multiple test among diffrent os,the config is as follows:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - name: "build on linux"
      os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      services: docker
    - name: "build on mac"
      os: osx
      osx_image: xcode10
      env: CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    - name: "build on windows"
      os: windows
```

I expected all the OS would run the build, but only the first triggered, the others was ignored for some reason.

The link of the config of the travis-ci is [here](https://travis-ci.org/yunnysunny/node-rdkafka/builds/522749727/config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that travis's `jobs` key tends to override `matrix:includes`.

Have you tried removing the `jobs` system to see if the `matrix` works?

Comment: I has removed the `matrix` key and keep the `jobs` key, and it seemed working now.